# Why doesn't the Objective-c runtime set dealloc'd object instances to nil?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, runtime

Sometimes I set objects to `nil` after releasing them to avoid crashes due to unexpected messages sent to `dealloc`'d objects.

Why doesn't the Objective-c runtime do this **automatically** when an object is finally `dealloc`'d?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because pointers are passed by value and not reference. All `dealloc` gets is a local copy of the pointer; any changes it makes are discarded. Same goes for C's `free` and C++'s `delete`.

Answer (score 3):

How would the runtime be able to track down all such references?

```
MyClass* a = [MyClass new];
MyClass* aCopy = a;
[a release];
a = nil;  // Tidy up
[aCopy crashNowPlease];
```

Sometimes you can catch this sort of thing with Build & Analyze.

Also, you will be able to use zeroing weak references in the future (or, Mike Ash [created such a facility](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-07-16-zeroing-weak-references-in-objective-c.html)).

Answer (score 3):

In objective-C, the objects are always accessed as pointer.
Setting an object to nil simply change the pointer value, not the object value.

In your method, you have only access to the object's value, not to the pointer pointing to it!

As @David Dunham says, you can have more than one pointer to an object, so how would the compiler knows?

And more than that, to make things easier, imagine the following code :

```
int a;
int* aPtr = &a;
```

If you change `a` value, you can access the changed value via `*aPtr` right? But you can change `a` value as long as you want, it won't change `aPtr` value, as it is not the same variable!

Thus, even if you only have one pointer to your object, if you modify the object's value, you pointer will still point to the same address value!

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is called a zeroing weak reference. This feature is available in OS X 10.7's Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) runtime. Prior to 10.7, you can use Mike Ash's zeroing weak reference [implementation](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-07-16-zeroing-weak-references-in-objective-c.html).

Without explicit runtime support (and some small but unavoidable overhead), standard C-style pointers (`id` in Objective-C is a pointer to a structure) are just a memory address (an integer) and not tracked by the runtime. There's nothing stopping you from making copies of this value elsewhere in memory *or* from storing the value in an integer of the appropriate size and casting to an `id` later on (of course if you do any of this, you kill a baby seal). Thus, when an object is dealloc'd there's no way to know where (or how many) references there are to that object.